# When I call the function in Text Widget, I get this display in my screen "instance of Future dynamic"?

Tags: flutter

This is the function, I want to retrieve currentUser data.

```
getData() async {
    User? user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
    print(user?.displayName);
  }
```

How to display the name on the screen
When I call the function in text widget i.e

> Text(getData().toString()),

I get the following display **Instance of 'Future'<'dynamic'>''**

i'm a beginner in Flutter, please help!

Answer (score 1):

Since the function `getData` is `async`, it's a `Future` and you can't use a future methods inside your tree widget directly

you can use it inside your widget tree using the widget `FutureBuilder`

```
FutureBuilder(
    future: getData(),
    builder: (context, snapshot){
        if (!snapshot.hasData) return const SizedBox();
        return Text(snapshot.data?.toString() ?? '');
}
```

also, you have to modify your method to make it return something,
Ex.:

```
getData() async {
    User? user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
    print(user?.displayName);
    return user?.displayName;
}
```

---

**UPDATE:**
to access all the info you want from the `User` object, let your method return the whole object;

```
getData() async {
    User? user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
    print(user?.displayName);
    return user;
}
```

and your `FutureBuilder` will be

```
FutureBuilder(
    future: getData(),
    builder: (context, snapshot){
        if (!snapshot.hasData) return const SizedBox();
        if (snapshot.data == null) return const Text('Current user is null');
        return Column(
            children: [
                Text('Name: ${snapshot.data?.displayName}'),
                Text('Email: ${snapshot.data?.email}'),
                ///Add any attribute you want to show..
            ]
        );
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I have one doubt, if I want to display email_id, what should be the code for that?

Answer (score 0):

```
    getData() async {
        User? user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
if(user!=null){
        print(user.displayName);
        print(user.email);}
      }
```

this will wait for an async method to first complete then print

Comment: Hi. Thank you! Can you tell me how to display email id as well?

Comment: I have updated my answer you can get email as you are getting name